# How to get the JSON object from the given code?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using a url my code is:

```
var url="http://nucleus/api/projectlist?format=json" 
var json=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

The JSON formatted data in the browser is like as follows

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "91",
        "title": "Nucleus Aura",
        "project_locations": "TVm, Kochi",
        "project_type": "Villa",
        "project_status": "Book Now",
        "count_plan": 0,
        "image": "uploads/project_images/projects_images_image1415954647.png",
        "imagetitle": "Villa Night"
    }
}
```

I want to print the JSON data object to an alert box.

Comment: Clarify your question, please...

Comment: Just to confirm... You are making the actual AJAX call (even though you didn't post that code) correct? If not you'll need to make the AJAX call for this to work.

Comment: format the Code  using `{}` well!

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to `var` to get an Object.
If responseText is as

```
{
    "one": {
        "id": "91",
        "title": "Nucleus Aura",
        "project_locations": "TVm, Kochi",
        "project_type": "Villa",
        "project_status": "Book Now",
        "count_plan": 0,
        "image": "uploads/project_images/projects_images_image1415954647.png",
        "imagetitle": "Villa Night"
    }
}
```

Then,

```
getJSON(url, function(json){
    alert(json);// will give output like [object][Object]
    alert(json.one.id);// will give output 91
}
```

Comment: thanks vikrant but i am not using jquery i want get it from a url   var url="http://nucleus/api/projectlist?format=json"; var json=JSON.parse(this.responseText);   how can i display the values to an alert box

Comment: If `this.responseText` gives your json string then you can assign it to `var` and simply alert it

Comment: try out the answer now!

Comment: pls check my question once more plss... vikrant  sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

```
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};

var url = "http://nucleus/api/projectlist?format=json";
getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result); //you can comment this, i used it to debug

    result.innerText = data.result; //display the result in an HTML element
}, function(status) { //error detection....
alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

Comment: rex how can i add this code to perform when a button onclick event? could you pls help me?